# Why it's "Yes, I have" rather than "Yes. I have"?

Tags: grammar, punctuation

I have been watching a video here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FVmVP9CCRcU

[image]

Why we use a *comma* rather than a *period* after Yes / No?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The word "Yes" on its own isn't a full sentence.  I suppose you could make some claim that it was short for something that is a full sentence. But why bother to jump through those logical loops.

English has a form of punctuation that is for separating phrases that are not sentences, the comma.

Comment: Yes. You're right.

Comment: It might be written with a full stop if the speaker said "Yes" abruptly and then paused before saying something more. Normally, it would be considered impolite to answer a question with just "Yes" or "No", so we say "Yes, I have", "No, it isn't" etc.

Comment: @KateBunting so adding the formal “it isn't” automatically makes it more polite? [Not sure about that](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ohDB5gbtaEQ)...

Comment: Don't mix formality with politeness.  Often "polite" is the same as friendly, tactful and and less formal.  Just replying "Yes", or "Yes, I have" might be impolite, if the other person was trying to start a conversation. Instead you might say "Yes,  I've been trying to get in shape for ...  how about you?" Less formal, more polite.